# Wow Slider in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, wowslider

I'd like to use the Wow Slider in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5. Because, the Views folder in MVC 5 supports the `.cshtml` format, I tried the *insert into html* option but it didn't work. I also tried unsuccessfully to copy the "data1" and "image1" folder into Visual Studio.

Can anybody please help me address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add some codes in _layout.cshtml file of shared folder.

Here are these

```html
@Scripts.Render("~/engine1/wowslider")
@Scripts.Render("~/engine1/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/engine1/script")
```

And this works for me.